# App crash on using Fabric and TwitterKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've got this line of code on my application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method and it causes a crash saying:

'[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'

Anyone can help me with this one?

Here's the code that causing the crash:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"consumer_key" consumerSecret:@"secret_key"];
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]];
```

Comment: Did you go through all the steps here: http://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/twitterkit-setup.html#set-up-kit

Comment: Yes, I've followed all these steps from the documentation.

Comment: Check your actual Info.plist.  In mine I'm seeing an entry for "Fabric" that is a Dictionary with APIKey and Kits

Comment: It doesn't seem to appear when I directly follow the documentation you mentioned. But when I used the fabric application, the app crash doesn't occur anymore. But I wanted to use the consumer key and secret key from the apps.twitter.com, any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You should have received the key/secret for your app through Fabric.  I think Fabric uses different credentials that other ways of configuring an application to log into Twitter (OAuth, etc).

Comment: I'm referring to the one that is mentioned in this documentation http://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/configure-twitter-app.html
I have an existing app in apps.twitter.com, and I want to use the consumer_key and secret_key that was provided to me by apps.twitter.com instead of the one that was given by Fabrics. Because they refer to two different apps.

Comment: I could be wrong - but I think the secret/key for Fabric/Twitter kit is different than a standard authentication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alex from Fabric here. To use different Twitter API keys or API keys generated on apps.twitter.com, you're declaring it correctly in your code above. It sounds like you may not have fully onboarded your app through the Fabric app, and required entries, like the Fabric `APIKey`, are missing from your `info.plist`.

**Some more info on the Fabric Mac App and info.plist:**

When you onboard an kit through the Mac App, a `Fabric` Dictionary entry is injected into your `info.plist`. Under the `Fabric` parent, there will be two children entries: `APIKey` and `Kits`.

[image]

Your Fabric API key, if it's not injected for some reason (it should be added automatically if you're using the Fabric app) or you want to manually change it, can be found by visiting https://fabric.io/settings/organizations, clicking your organization and clicking "API Key" below the organization title.

The `Kits` array contains an `Item X` for each Fabric kit you've included. If you've included Twitter Kit, the automatically provisioned consumerKey and consumerSecret are listed under `KitInfo`.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for! Thanks for the help. Another question though, can i still see my app on Fabric after using the keys that apps.twitter.com gave me?

Comment: On the Fabric dashboard you mean? If so, then yep. As long as you onboard your app through Fabric, it's going to appear in your dashboard.

Comment: It does show the app, but it doesn't display the consumer_key and secret key that I'm using. Also take note that we also have an Android version of this app. And we are sharing the same keys that we got from apps.twitter.com

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On the Twitter dashboard on fabric.io, you'll always see the Fabric generated consumerKey and consumerSecret. We want to make those available to you to use so we don't replace them with your apps.twitter.com keys. You can definitely share your apps.twitter.com key between Android and iOS apps, that's really up to you. You'll need to consider rate limits if you're sharing the key between apps, but it's totally doable.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Why do we need to put consumer secret in info.plist? Wouldn't that be equal to sharing the secret as plain text with anyone? Your setting page specifically says to never share the secret in plaintext with anyone.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Here is a specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723182/twitter-consumer-secret-really-a-secret

Comment: My question is slightly related to this. I am adding twitter login thru FirebaseUI not using twitter kit at all. 
and I am having the error 
'TWTRInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'Attempted to call TwitterKit methods before calling the requisite start methods; you must call +[Fabric with:@[Twitter class]] before using the methods on TwitterKit. If you are not storing your consumerKey and consumerSecret in your application's info.plist you must also call -[TwitterKit startWithConsumerKey:consumerSecret:] before calling +[Fabric with:]'

Any clue for me?

Answer (score 3):

I followed the steps as described above but still was getting this error

> uncaught exception 'TWTRInvalidInitializationException', reason:
>   'Attempted to call TwitterKit methods before calling the requisite
>   start methods; you must call +[Fabric with:@[Twitter class]] before
>   using the methods on TwitterKit

As i am using multiple kits i tried to initialize on different calls as follows

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter class]]];
```

As per Fabric documentation for + (instancetype)with:(NSArray *)kitClasses;

> Only the first call to this method is honored. Subsequent calls are
>   no-ops.
>   So only Crashlytics was initializing and Twitter got ignored.

**Solution** was to initialize as follows;

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Twitter class]]];
```