# Twitter consumer secret really a secret?

Tags: twitter, oauth

For writing desktop twitter apps, one is required to create an app at apps.twitter.com and use consumer "secret" to retrieve the user's authorization via some sort of PIN.

The apps page on twitter says:

> Keep the "Consumer Secret" a secret. This key should never be human-readable in your application.

Is this a joke? The client app needs to have it in plaintext at some point. Is this Twitter's sense of security? And does it really matter to keep this "secret" a secret? (which is obviously impossible)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question and is simply a rant.

Comment: I voted it up because I Googled this.

Comment: And the last sentence really isn't a rant either: "And does it really matter to keep this 'secret' a secret?" but a valid and significant question considering that Twitter is one of the largest websites world-wide and provides a login service that can be used by any other application out there. In general, my impression is that security issues aren't cared about enough, which is also showing by having no authoritative answers here yet (among many other things like GWT's XSRF implementation which seems to be XSRF-vulnerable by itself).

Comment: @Ash I understand your concerns, and it's a common one shared by many developers.  There are a number of places where discussion of those concerns is appropriate.  SO is not one of them; SO is for people to ask and answer specific technical questions.